# Wordpress Delete User after Success

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a form we want users to access only once, anonymously.  We hand out randomly generated usernames and passwords to allow anonymity.  I would like to delete user, log off and redirect after successful submission.

I am able to delete the user with wp_delete_user($thisId); but alwyas have a "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" error.  I'm not sure how to approach this one.

I am processing in header.php

Answer (score 0):

If you process in `header.php` it's too late because the server is already sending the page.

Try hooking your "delete_user" function in a previous action such as `init` or `wp` like this (in `functions.php`):

```
add_action('init', 'my_delete_user_process');

function my_delete_user_process(){

    // Do your stuff

    $user_id = get_current_user_id()
    wp_delete_user($user_id);

    // Do your stuff
}
```